# Firefox: Can I have a visible address bar when the window is narrow?

Tags: firefox

Sometimes I like to put a browser window on half the screen instead of fullscreen. But then the address bar gets tiny which is very annoying when I want to edit the url.
[image: tiny]
I think it used to overflow the addon buttons into a `>>` menu the way it does bookmarks, or maybe that's wishful thinking. Is there a way to get it to overflow addons into a menu instead of hiding the URL?

Also, why does it add so much space before the `>>`, that's ridiculous (and no I did not manually add a spacer there). And there are now *three* of those site icons for per-domain settings/security/cookies, can't they be collapsed into one? and both the translations addon and and multi-account containers also pollute the url bar</rant>

EDIT: With compact mode on:
[image: compact]

Answer (score 1):

Do this (as long as it still works) :

- Go to `about:config` in the address bar
- If a warning appears, click "Accept the Risk" and Continue
- Type `browser.compactmode.show`
- Double-click the entry to set it to `true`
- Restart Firefox
- Click *Settings > More tools > Customize toolbar…*
- At the bottom click "Density"
- Choose "Compact (not supported)"
- You may also hover over user-interface elements and close them by
  clicking the X or move them around
- Click "Done" when finished
- You may return to the previous state by selecting Density as Normal.

Reference :
[Compact mode workaround in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/compact-mode-workaround-firefox).

Comment: Thanks, that gives me 8 more letters. Guess it's an improvement  ¯\\(°_o)/¯